# How to cache internet content using Windows Server 2012? TMG not compatible

Tags: windows, tmg

I am surprised because TMG 2010 is not compatible with Windows Server 2012, and there is no other product to replace it.

So, I want to cache internet content in a Windows Server 2012 to accelerate the response time of the queries of the client machines in the internal network to the internet, namely cache http queries

Before it was so easy to do it, using Windows Server 2008 and TMG (or even ISA Server), but now, someone knows any Microsoft product to cache internet content or how to create a web proxy service in windows server 2012?

Thanks

Comment: maybe get a windows version of squid.

Comment: I'm sad that Microsoft quit TMG. I liked it.

Comment: Surprised? I WAS surprised about that when it was announced more than 1.5 years ago. Today this is like "I am surprised earth is round". The  product end of life is old old old news.

Answer (score 1):

Hy, that's may not the answer you expect but atm there is no alternative from MS. Insteed our company is using Citrix Netscaler VPX as an replacment of our TMG Server.

https://www.citrix.de/products/netscaler-application-delivery-controller/features/platforms/vpx.html

It's a bit more expensive but real powerfull.

br

Answer (score 1):

Hi we moved to squid with an SSL bump to replace TMG as a caching proxy.

Sadly a TMG replacement is not within the MS product line